git complains about disabled certificate verification despite, http.sslVerify=true
Git gives me some warnings that the tls verification has been disabled, but
❯ git config --get --show-origin http.sslVerify
file:.git/config        true
❯ env | grep GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY
❯ git --version
git version 2.45.2

the strange thing is that the message is repeated several times. a few days ago it was always twice but suddenly its a lot more:
❯ git fetch
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: auto-detection of host provider took too long (>2000ms)
warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/autodetect for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: auto-detection of host provider took too long (>2000ms)
warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/autodetect for more information.
[normal fetch ouput]

How can I get rid of this or investigate this further?
In case that matters: Iam behind a password proxy and the settings are also within the git config

OK That's a hard one. I can try and guess some potential issues.

Maybe you have the envvar GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY set?
Maybe the certificate is self-signed and trusted


this variable does not seem to be set. how can I check the second possibilitiy? but the remote is on github so I doubt

Add --verbose and see if there is more information around the warning?

--verbose does not add anything to these lines
